# retrieving un-named jupyter lab files after anaconda uninstall

Tags: linux, rhel, datascience-anaconda

So I got a message from somebody at Anaconda that I should refrain from using anaconda3 since it's not allowed within a company context to use it. Because I mainly used it as a launcher for `jupyter` notebooks, I uninstalled it. Of course, me being stupid I forgot to save my open panels before doing that. When I launched it from the command line I was presented with an empty workspace.

I tried copying the `.anaconda3_backup` workspace but that didn't really help a lot.

Would there be a way to retrieve what was in that workspace, knowing that the files may NOT have been saved as `.pynbk`? I have been searching with `updatedb`/`locate` and `grep` in the backup dir but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try to search for the expansion ".ipynb". Opening a Jupyter workspace usually just opens the directory you are in. So the notebooks shouldn't be lost. Try: `find . -name "*.ipynb"` in your home folder for example